# Using the same database on another Subdomain

Tags: themes, database, templates, shared-hosting, customization

Hi i am currently replacing my blog run on wordpress  with another neat theme. I tried the preview template feature and everything is fine, just that i don't trust everything so easily when it comes to web-applications. So i want to use the same database currently used[meaning not to use same database for both sites, but make a copy of the database/something with the data/posts] with the post/article and then perfect the theme with the data then replace the old with new.
I would like detailed steps for just the database part others i can handle :)
thanks for any and every help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the [built-in exporter/importer](http://codex.wordpress.org/Importing_Content#WordPress). Export from the existing site, and import into the new site. You won't ever even need to touch the database.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a tutorial on how to export / import your WordPress database and run the queries you'll need so the new site works: http://web-kreation.com/tutorials/migrating-a-wordpress-site-ftp-phpmyadmin-and-sql-queries/

If you just want a local environment so you can play around with themes, this is a good tutorial for setting that up on your Mac: http://loneplacebo.com/how-to-install-mamp-on-mac-for-local-wordpress-theme-development/

And here's how you could do that on a PC: http://return-true.com/2010/09/setting-up-xampp-wordpress-for-local-testing/

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

I recently gave these instructions in [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/23327/db-connection-error-after-copying-a-wordpress-multisite-instance-to-a-second-loca/#answer-23753).

Short Version:

Use find/replace on the domain and path in the sql dump file.